# VMware Fusion: Stale NFS file handle w/o NFS

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, vmware-fusion

Here's a pretty strange one: I am getting the following error in a VMware Fusion Virtual Machine:

```
cannot access /usr/share/postgresql: Stale NFS file handle
```

The weird part being that this is not actually an NFS mount; I don't even have the NFS client *installed* on this server! I'm not really sure where to go with this as *mount -O* and restarting don't fix anything. I've restored snapshots as old as a week, when things were working fine, without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen it relatively often that a "stale NFS file handle" really indicates that a file system is corrupted or unclean - try running `fsck` on it.

Comment: Heh, that hadn't even crossed my mind. Running fsck automatically on reboot (then manually when that failed) fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this probably has nothing to do with VMware Fusion. You are, as Tim states, probably just having issues with the filesystem on your VM.

Also, there is no "NFS client"; it is probably built in to the kernel of your Linux distro as a, well, filesystem.

Comment: That's the case for some OSes, say FreeBSD, but isn't so with Ubuntu. I would need to install the nfs-client package.